# C++ default, copy and promotion constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have the following code [This is an interview question]:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A(){
        cout << endl << "base default";
    }
    A(const A& a){
        cout << endl << "base copy ctor";
    }
    A(int) { 
        cout << endl << "base promotion ctor";
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
    B(){
         cout << endl << "derived default";
    }
    B(const B& b){
         cout << endl << "derived copy ctor";
    }
    B(int) {
         cout << endl << "derived promotion ctor";
    }
};

int main(){

    vector<A> cont;
    cont.push_back(A(1));
    cont.push_back(B(1));
    cont.push_back(A(2));

        return 0;
    }
```

The output is :

```
base promotion ctor
base copy ctor
base default
derived promotion ctor
base copy ctor
base copy ctor
base promotion ctor
base copy ctor
base copy ctor
base copy ctor
```

I am having trouble understanding this output, specifically why base default is called once and the last 3 copy ctor. Can someone please explain this output ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please either reply to the comment or ask a new question. It is a new question, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the edit is a separate question; I did try reserve().

Comment: They have the exact sequence - http://ideone.com/TUEGo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base default constructor is called once from the line

```
cont.push_back(B(1));
```

All your `B` constructors call the default `A` constructor. The last two copy constructors are because of a vector re-allocation. For example, if you added

```
cont.reserve(3);
```

before the `push_back`s, they'd go away.

The one before that is a copy of the temporary `A(2)` in your final `push_back`.

Comment: In addition to having a vector large enough so it does not resize; also note: If you compile with optimization turned on then a couple of copy constructors would disappear as the compiler optimizes them out.

Comment: why does the A(2) push_back have the sequence : base copy ctor
base promotion ctor, base copy ctor whereas A(1) push_back just has : base promotion ctor , base copy ctor